What type of drywall patch filler is this?
Previous owners patched the drywall in one location but it looks absolutely atrocious.

Do you think this is a spackle that's thrown in there, or something else? Mostly curious more than anything else. I'll scrape/sand it down and patch with mud in either case, but just curious what he might have been thinking here.

There's really no way to tell if it's a particular type of filler from this picture. Could be joint compound, spackle, plaster...
It's a bad patch. That's more a matter of the previous worker not knowing what they were doing with the material than what material it was.

It's really hard to see through that paint what filler was used, if you're lucky some sort of plaster, if you're unlucky cement or steel filled bondo.
Rasp it flat with a saw blade (tape both ends so they skate) , sand it smooth and fill any divots.

Thanks. Do you have a picture for what you mean by tape both ends so they skate? Just want to make sure I understand what you're saying. I was able to scrape off some of the material that's above the drywall plane with a scraper tool, so I don't think it's something really hard.

I mean wrap tape on the tip and the back of the saw blade so it cant cut the wall,  ir gets you a tool that mill make fast work of excess plaster without generating clouds of dust,
